# Get a specific implementation of a parametrized trait from a parametrized function

Tags: scala, functional-programming, traits, case-class, coproduct

Trying to get a parametrized function that would return the specified coproduct of a trait.

```
sealed trait Tr { def x: Int }
case class Cl1(x: Int) extends Tr
case class Cl2(x: Int) extends Tr

def getTr[A <: Tr](i: Int): A = {
  ???
}
```

How can this be achieved in Scala 2.11?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a TypeTag for `A` and compare it to `Cl1` and `Cl2`:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

def getTr[A <: Tr : TypeTag](i: Int): Tr =
  if (typeOf[A] <:< typeOf[Cl1]) Cl1(i)
  else if (typeOf[A] <:< typeOf[Cl2]) Cl2(i)
  else ??? // etc

getTr[Cl1](42) // Cl1(42)
getTr[Cl2](42) // Cl2(42)
```

Note that I had to change the return type to `Tr`. It can't work with `A` because the compiler wouldn't allow having branches that resolve into different types for `A` (we don't know the actual `A`, but it surely can't be both `Cl1` and `Cl2` at the same time). Side note: [GADTs](https://gist.github.com/smarter/2e1c564c83bae58c65b4f3f041bfb15f) actually have a bit of special treatment by the compiler which allows such cases, e.g.:

```
object Test {
  def eval[T](e: Expr[T]): T = e match {
    case IntExpr(i) => i  // is T Int?
    case BoolExpr(b) => b // ...or is it Boolean?
  }
}
```

By the way, is your question a contrived example or a real scenario? If it's the latter, I feel it should be possible to implement it in a more elegant way.

Comment: Real-life scenario. Yeah, found a better way just by composing functions.